# Effectively closed computable functions

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, terminology

I've recently been interested in the following type of functions. A total computable function *f*:**N**→**N** is *effectively closed* if there is a computable function *p* such that *f*[**N** \ W<sub>e</sub>] = **N** \ W<sub>*p*(e)</sub>, where W<sub>e</sub> is the e-th c.e. set.

> Have effectively closed functions been studied? If so, what are they normally called?

I would also appreciate pointers to some uses and/or alternative characterizations of effectively closed functions.

**Motivation.** It is well-known that there is a near-perfect analogy between the adjectives *computable* and *continuous*. For example, a total function *f*:**N**→**N** is computable if and only if it is effectively continuous, i.e. there is a computable function *p* such that *f*<sup>-1</sup>[W<sub>e</sub>] = W<sub>*p*(e)</sub>. [For the backward implication, let *q* be a computable function such that W<sub>*q*(n)</sub> = {n} and use the composite *p*∘*q* to enumerate the graph of *f*.] A similar trick shows that a total function is effectively open if and only if it is computable. However, a total computable function is not necessarily effectively closed since that entails that the range of *f* is computable and, indeed, that *f* maps every computable set onto a computable set. Also, the notion is nontrivial since non-constant polynomials and increasing functions are effectively closed.

---

**Update.** Joel David Hamkins gave the following characterization of effectively closed computable functions: they are the computable functions *f*:**N**→**N** for which there is a computable *b*:**N**→**N** such that *f*<sup>-1</sup>(n) ⊆ {0,1,...,b(n)} for every n ∈ **N**. Although I accepted Joel's answer, the main question is still open.

Comment: François, it's a great problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like your concept a lot, and have been able to find a characterization.

Suppose that $f:N\to N$ is effectively closed in your sense.

First, as you mentioned, it is easy to see that $\text{ran}(f)$ is
computable, since by taking $W_e$ to be empty your equation shows that
$\text{ran}(f)$ is both c.e. and co-c.e.

Second, I claim that $f$ is finite-to-one. To see this,
 suppose that $f^{-1}(k)$ is infinite for some $k$. Define
 a c.e. set $W_e$ as follows: At stage $s$, if we see that
 $k$ is still not in $W_{\rho(e),s}$, the state-$s$ approximation
 to $W_{\rho(e)}$, then enumerate the next element of
 $f^{-1}(k)$ into $W_e$. (Although this definition may look
 circular, since I am defining $W_e$ by reference to
 $W_{\rho(e)}$, the definition is legitimate by an
 application of the Recursion Theorem. That is, I really
 define $W_{r(e)}$, and then find $e$ such that $W_e=W_{r(e)}$.)
 Note that if $k$ is never enumerated into $W_{\rho(e)}$,
 then I will eventually put all of $f^{-1}(k)$ into $W_e$,
 which will result in $k\notin f[N-W_e]$, but $k\in
 N-W_{\rho(e)}$, a contradiction. Alternatively, if $k\in
 W_{\rho(e),s}$, then $f^{-1}(k)\cap W_e$ has at most
 $s$ members, and so there are $a\in N-W_e$ with $f(a)=k$,
 placing $k$ into $f[N-W_e]$ but not in $N-W_{\rho(e)}$,
 again a contradiction.

A similar argument shows actually that the
 function $k\mapsto f^{-1}(k)$ is computable. Namely,
 define the set $W_e$ by the following procedure. At stage
 $s$, look at every $k\leq s$, and if $k\notin
 W_{\rho(e),s}$, then enumerate all of $f^{-1}(k)\cap s$ into
 $W_e$. (Again, appeal to Recursion Theorem to get such an
 $e$.) In other words, as long as $k$ is not in
 $W_{\rho(e),s}$, then we put all elements of $f^{-1}(k)$
 below $s$ into $W_e$.

If $k\notin W_{\rho(e)}$, then $f^{-1}(k)\subset W_e$, and
 so $k\notin f[N-W_e]$, contradicting $k\in N-W_{\rho(e)}$.
 Thus, $W_{\rho(e)}=N$. From this, it follows that $W_e=N$.
 Now, note that $k\in W_{\rho(e)}$ implies $k\in W_{\rho(e),s_k}$
 for some stage $s_k$, and so $f^{-1}(k)$ is a subset of $s_k$.
 By applying $f$ to each value below $s_k$, we see that the
 map $k\mapsto f^{-1}(k)$ is a computable function.

This means that $f$ has a particularly simple form.
 Namely, there is a computable partition $N=\bigsqcup_k
 B_k$, with each $B_k$ finite, such that $f$ maps elements of
 $B_k$ to $k$. (Note that some $B_k$ may be empty.)

Conversely, every function with such a form is
 computably closed in your sense. Suppose that $f$ arises
 from such a computable partition of $N$ into finite sets
 $B_k$. Given any program $e$, enumerate $k$ into $W_{\rho(e)}$ when
 all of $B_k$ gets enumerated into $W_e$. It follows that
 $f[N-W_e]=N-W_{\rho(e)}$, as desired.

This provides a characterization of the effectively  closed
computable functions:

**Theorem.** A computable function $f:N\to N$ is
effectively closed if and only if $f$ is finite-to-one and
the map $k\mapsto f^{-1}(k)$ is computable.

Comment: This is great! I had gotten the finite-to-one part using a completely different argument, but not the computable bound on $f^{-1}(k)$.

Comment: This doesn't answer the main question, but I'm accepting it anyway since the argument is so beautiful!

Comment: I think there's a minor error in the 6th paragraph: "that $W_e=N$" should be "that $W_e = ran(f)$."

Comment: I think $W_e=N$ is correct. The point is that once you know $W_{\rho(e)}=N$, then $N-W_{\rho(e)}$ is empty, so it had better be that $W_e=N$ or else $f[N-W_e]$ won't be empty. Or have I misunderstood? 

Comment: Never mind, that was a silly typo I made when copying your argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is probably studied in Russian/Markov School of Constructivism. A good starting point might be the chapters on Russian Constructivism in Michael Beeson's book:

Michael Beeson, "Foundations of Constructive Mathematics: Metamathematical Studies", Springer, 1985

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are citing this reference?  Most of us don't have this book, so perhaps you could supply a relevant sentence or two -- otherwise such a comment is not very useful.